# Disabling JavaScript errors in WebBrowser control in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-oob

I'm developing Silverlight OOB application and I need to show web pages in it - I would like to do it through out WebBrowser control, but during page load I get lots of MessageBoxes with JavaScript errors.

Is there a way of hiding those MessageBoxes?

In winform WebBrowser control there is `ScriptErrorsSuppressed` property that can be used, but in SL there isn't.

I would be appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I've returned to this problem in my app and I was able to resolve it somehow. Because I need to show only a pages - without much user interaction on those pages - I solve it this way.

In code I create a html with iframe with attribute `security="restricted"` and then I inject url to this iFrame.

My code looks like this:

```
var html = new StringBuilder(@"<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" lang=""EN""> 
                                            <head> 
                                            <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=utf-8"" /> 
                                            <title>{@pageTitle}</title> 
                                            <style type=""text/css""> 
                                            html {overflow: auto;} 
                                            html, body, div, iframe {margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 100%; border: none;} 
                                            iframe {display: block; width: 100%; border: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;} 
                                            </style> 
                                            </head> 
                                            <body> 
                                            <iframe id=""tree"" name=""tree"" security=""restricted"" src=""{@PageLink}"" frameborder=""0"" marginheight=""0"" marginwidth=""0"" width=""100%"" height=""100%"" scrolling=""auto""></iframe> 
                                            </body> 
                                            </html>");
html.Replace("{@pageTitle}", Title);
html.Replace("{@PageLink}", uri.ToString());
```

and then I'm using `NavigateToString` method of `WebBrowser` to load my html to it.

P.S. I've added this as an answer to accept this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off script debugging in the internet explorers advanced settings.  Ultimately the control uses MSHTML to deliver the rendering, which in turn gets many of it settings from IE.

Comment: I have disabled script debugging in IE, but the problem still occurs. So it's a problem with the control.

Comment: I have a feeling that this can be done through reflection, but I don't see any good method for that ;)